# How do I detect two different teams in the same area?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Trying to recreate Zedaf's Proximity map in 1.13, but ran in the problem of making opposing team members visible on the same island. First, I thought to make an execute `unless` command

```
/execute unless @a[team=blue,team=red,x=-200,y=30,z=-600,distance=..10] run effect give @a[team=blue]
```

together with

```
/execute unless @a[team=blue,team=red,x=-200,y=30,z=-600,distance=..10] run effect give @a[team=red]
```

but that would be detecting someone on both teams. The main question is how do I make it where if two separate teams are in the same are in the same area then no more invisibility for the people in **that area alone**, but if only one team is present then they remain invisible.

I can only find answers with the `testfor` function which does not exist in 1.13.

Comment: Give everyone invisibility, execute at everyone from team A->clear invisibility for everyone in team B in a radius.

Comment: Won't that clear invisibility if there are members of team A close to other members of team A? And it would only clear it form team B?

Comment: No. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need a command like this:

```
/execute at @e[team=blue] run effect clear @e[team=red,distance=..10] invisibility
```

The `execute` part moves the command execution point to every member of team blue. The `effect clear` part after it is then limited to only members of team red in a radius around these blue players. So only blue players who are close to red players become visible.

Comment: Hey, I'm getting better with the 1.13 commands! I didn't have to look up anything to write this answer.